# amung.us and "users online" time window

Tags: analytics

Greetings i would like to ask you what is the time window that amung.us calculates "online" users. 1 hour? 30 min? 15 min? other?????

Comment: Try reading their Help page.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer is every "few seconds" -- which comes from their site...**

"Near the top of the page, **the number of people currently on the site that these stats are for is displayed, updated every few seconds**. Below that, a timeline shows visitor trends for the previous 24 hours. You can click on it to view specific ranges in history. Under the timeline, in the left column we'll show you a few of the most popular pages right now on your website, and how many people are on each page. Beside the list to the right is a map display where people are in the world. Clicking on the list or map takes you to a more detailed stats page."

**SOURCE:** http://whos.amung.us/help/stats/#q1

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this information is not what i was asking for. the "updated every few seconds" has nothing to do with the time window of the online users. the "every few seconds" is for the display of stats. i need to know the time window that defines the "online users".

Comment: to give another example of what i need to know:

Comment: if amung.us shows "100 visitors online" these whats the maximum difference of time between the first and the last visitor. (excuse me for the multiple comments -i just pressed enter to change line but instead it posted the comment :P )

Comment: @Kari_kari:Just email them and ask... ;-)